# How was this p-value calculated?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, self-study, p-value

Sorry to ask such a blunt question, but I'm running out of time and I just can't figure this seemingly simple thing out. It's the p-value for $B_0$, a single variable regression. $H_0: B_0=0$ and $H_1: B0 \neq 0$. $T_{calc} = (0.5681 - 0)/0.9284 = 0.6119$. Then it says $p\text{-value}=2 \cdot (t\ge 0,6119) =2 \cdot 0.281525$. Where is this $0.281525$ coming from? I know it has something to do with the table. $n=8$.

Sorry again, I have a test coming up, for some reason I can't figure this out. I spent way too much time on this now, watching youtube videos for the past 1.5 hours trying to figure out where this .2815... came from.

Comment: The exact format of t-tables varies a bit from one table to another. Can you print what the n = 8 row looks like?  These days, these things are usually figured out by computer, without tables.

Comment: 1.44 1.94 2.45 3.14 3.71

sorry no that was for 6, because I was assuming n-k-1 degrees of freedom. for 8 it is:

1.4 1.86 2.31 2.9 3.36

Comment: If that is it, then they didn't use that table.

Answer (score 5):

A [p-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value) is the probability of a statistic at least as extreme as the one observed if the null hypothesis is true.

The value 0.281525 is the area to the right of 0.6119 on a t-density with 6 degrees of freedom.

[image]

That area represents a probability of being at least as large as the observed t-statistic. We then double it, because a value at -0.6119 is equally as extreme (in the other direction), which we must account for in a two-tailed test.

Comment: So if I have nothing but the t-table on paper, how do I know which p-value to use?

Comment: That depends on how your tables are organized, but the typical one-page tables probably don't show upper tail areas bigger than about 0.25. So, for example see the 6df row of [this table](http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~mripol/3024/Fall2010/tTableDistribution.jpg). The smallest value there is 0.718, which has an area of 0.25 to the right of it. Your t-value is smaller, so the upper tail area is *bigger than* 0.25, and so the p-value is more than $2\times 0.25$; you'd write $p>0.5$ in that case.